# current_user_can('administrator') returns false when I'm logged in

Tags: rest-api, authentication

```
  protected function isAdmin() : bool {
    $check = current_user_can('administrator');
    return $check; 
    // returns false as I am logged in as superadmin, refreshing the page for xdebug to run
  }
```

`$check` also evaluates to false when using `current_user_can('delete_site');`

My wordpress install is hosted on my local machine, Lubuntu 18.04 with apache2. Php 7.2. I can access the site by navigating to `http://localhost/folderName` in Google Chrome.

I have cookie auth enabled and see my user cookie is present with the EditThisCookie Chrome extension.

In the xdebug console (of Phpstorm 2019.2) I also get a false response:

```
current_user_can('delete_site');
false

‌‌current_user_can('administrator');
‌false
```

I have no issues navigating around the front or back end of the wordpress site as an Admin. I feel like this might be an environment issue due to the discrepency betwen the Chrome experience and what the plugin and Xdebug are catching.

Does anyone know why I am running into this issue?

Comment: Where are you running this code? If you’re running it too early the current user won’t be set.

Comment: @JacobPeattie It is being run in a rest api request handler callback. The admin user clicks on a delete icon next to a table row which executes the request. the request handler is hooked as an action to `rest_api_init`

Comment: You need to send a nonce with REST requests for the current user to be recognised: https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/authentication/#cookie-authentication

Comment: @JacobPeattie the nonce solution turned out to be the right one, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally for checking for administration privileges you have to check the “manage_options” capability, such as:

```
current_user_can('manage_options')
```

Alternatively, you want to list the roles with wp_get_current_user()->roles and ensure the “Administrator” role is in that array.

The capabilities you are checking for do not exist in a vanilla install of wp.

Comment: Thank you, I tried using `manage_options` but it still returned false. Then I ran `wp_get_current_user()->roles;` and got back an empty array. Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Can you please var_dump(wp_get_current_user()) and confirm you are logged in? Also, in case it's a MU install, try checking against the "manage_network" permission.

Comment: If you have more to add that can help us write good answers please edit your question and update us.

Comment: I can't seem to var dump it: `PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function admin\controllers\‌var_dump() in <path to php file> on line 117`. The debugger shows an empty array on $roles when I add the following line to the auth checking callback: `$roles = wp_get_current_user()->roles;` Now I'm looking into the reasons why the current WP_User object shows blanks or 0's for all properties.

Comment: Use ```\var_dump()``` with a slash at the beginning, so it will ignore your namespace.

Comment: it's not crashing but also not dumping to the page since this is an api request. I think maybe the fact that a React.js static .js application is handling the admin view might be the cause of the WP_User object having all properties 0/null/empty

Comment: Ok, I needed to pass the current user data from the server/PHP to the browser for the React app. When I ran `wp_get_current_user();` in the right place it worked

Comment: @SeanDezoysa please accept my answer if it helped =)